# Using database schemas to categorize tables in MySQL with Spring Boot and JPA/Hibernate

Tags: sql, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a Spring Boot project with JPA/Hibernate entities that connects to a MySQL database. I want to organize my tables into different categories (e.g., customer-related tables, order-related tables, etc.) without having to create multiple databases or resort to using prefixes or suffixes in the table names.

In PostgreSQL, I could use schemas to achieve this goal. However, I'm not sure if this approach is possible or recommended in MySQL. Is there a way to organize tables into categories within a single MySQL database while still maintaining good practices for naming conventions?

I've already tried creating multiple schemas within MySQL for each category of tables, and then updating my JPA/Hibernate entity classes with the appropriate schema name in the @Table annotation. However, this resulted in an error where it was unable to find the specified table in the correct schema.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly configure JPA/Hibernate to work with multiple schemas in MySQL? Or is there an alternative approach that would allow me to categorize my tables within a single database? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you are missing grants on the schema specific tables.

Comment: Please share how you defined the Table annotation of the entity class. And what error exactly did you get.

Comment: @Mar-Z
I'm not getting any error messages, I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: In MySQL they use the concept of catalog instead of schema. You can use it to categorize your tables. Then you can define a specific catalog as attribute in the @Table annotation of entity class.

Comment: @Mar-Z Please provide your answer with an example in Spring Boot here. If it solves my problem, I will confirm it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

To categorize database tables you can create different schema. This must be done directly on the database. For example:

```
CREATE SCHEMA customer;
CREATE SCHEMA order;
```

After doing it you can use the proper schema while creating the tables. You can even let JPA create the tables during the application start. This is good for testing but not recommended for production however.

You can provide the correct schema as an attribute to the @Entity annotation of the entity classes. For example:

```
@Table( schema = "customer")
public class Customer {
// ...
}

@Table( schema = "order")
public class Order {
// ...
}
```

The above solution will work for all databases types except of... MySQL. This is because MySQL driver use the concept of catalog instead of schema. Fortunately this default behavior can be changed with a property in the connection string. Like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?databaseTerm=SCHEMA
```

Comment: this solution create multiple database into mysql.

Comment: This is how MySQL implements the concept of categories of tables. There is no other way to do it with MySQL. Other databases like Oracle have similar concept of schema as a logical collection of database objects. Addressing  a column in SQL: <schema_name>.<table_name>.<column_name>

Comment: I am looking for a way to use only one database and have table categorization done within it(MySQL). I have previously mentioned this in my question, something like defining a schema in the PostgreSQL database.